# HttpURLConnection is not working with openJDK 11.0.8

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, openjdk-11, adoptopenjdk

I am trying to call API with HttpURLConnection using oracle JDK 11.0.1 and it's working fine with it, but same thing is not working with openJDK 11.0.8. Below is my request header.

```
connection.addRequestProperty("username", "test");
connection.addRequestProperty("password", "XXX");
connection.addRequestProperty("timestamp", "2021-03-08T11:24:16.698+0000");
connection.addRequestProperty("caller", "Test Rest Client/");
connection.addRequestProperty("authentication", "XXX");
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Here password header's value we will get through `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")` algorithm and authentication's value we will get through `Mac.getInstance("hmacSHA256")` algorithm